# Flexpaper in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, flexpaper

I am a newbie to CodeIgniter. I tried to use [flexpaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/) in my CodeIgniter code using my PHP knowledge in the view area alone, and it doen't seem to be working. It stops with document loading....

I am trying to display already converted documents. My actual problem is this: in the below JavaScript code which is in the view area of my CI, addresses a location in the line `SwfFile : escape(base)` in the below code; now where should the folder which contains the swf files be placed?

```js
var doc = '<?php print $doc; ?>';
var doc1 = '<?php print $doc1; ?>';
var base = 'swf/'+'<?php print $doc1; ?>';
var fp = new FlexPaperViewer(
                'FlexPaperViewer',
                'viewerPlaceHolder', { config : {
                    SwfFile : escape(base),
                    Scale : 0.6, 
                    ZoomTransition : 'easeOut',
                    ZoomTime : 0.5,
                    ZoomInterval : 0.2,
                    FitPageOnLoad : true,
                    FitWidthOnLoad : true,
                    PrintEnabled : true,
                    FullScreenAsMaxWindow : false,
                    ProgressiveLoading : false,
                    MinZoomSize : 0.2,
                    MaxZoomSize : 5,
                    SearchMatchAll : false,
                    InitViewMode : 'Portrait',

                    ViewModeToolsVisible : true,
                    ZoomToolsVisible : true,
                    NavToolsVisible : true,
                    CursorToolsVisible : true,
                    SearchToolsVisible : true,

                    localeChain: 'en_US'
                }});
```

Comment: What is 'flespaper'? Please explain more and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @Maher4Ever: http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/ . Was just a quick Google search away...

Comment: Alright, so you are trying to embed a flash snippet into one if the views and that breaks it. It would help to see the view's markup, because your problem might not be caused by codeigniter (nor by to php).

Comment: are you trying to display already converted documents ?

Answer (score 0):

I think flash files in CI have to be in the root of the application to work.

Answer (score 0):

To load your view files, you need to call:

```
$this->load->view('yourViewFile');
```

where in the view folder, the file name would be yourViewFile.php

In case if you haven't changed much in your codeigniter since after you downloaded it, this controller name should be `welcome.php` under application/controllers, and you can write the above code in your `index()` function!